# Grep: buscar primera palabra de una línea que contenga una letra

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Estoy intentando mostrar las líneas de un documento que empiecen por una palabra que contenga una t.

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
grep "^.*t.* " doc.txt
```

pero me salen más resultados de la misma línea, además de la primera palabra.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `grep '^[^ ]+' doc.txt | grep 't'`

La primera parte te mostrará la primera palabra de la línea, y utilizamos un pipe para filtrar y mostrar las que tienen la letra t

Comment: Gracias, pero la cuestión es que contenga t, no que empiece por t.

Comment: Tienes razón, no había leído con suficiente atención. Edito la respuesta